# How to dispatch different types from a ContT?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, continuations, continuation-passing

I want to create a generalized form of IO based on `ContT`. I created a GADT to represent different IO actions:

```
data Cmd a where
  PutChar :: Char -> Cmd ()
  GetChar :: Cmd Char
```

I wrote a function that transforms these into `IO` commands for use in the IO monad like so:

```
continueIO :: Cmd a -> IO a
continueIO (PutChar c) = putChar c
continueIO GetChar = getChar
```

Here's what a sample usage of this should look like:

```
echoChar :: (Monad m) => ContT r m (Cmd a)
echoChar = ContT $ \k -> do
  c <- k GetChar
  k (PutChar c)
```

It should be run with something like `runContT echoChar continueIO`. However, the `PutChar` and `GetChar` commands conflict in their types. How can I dispatch both types from the same ContT?

P.S. Sorry if anything in this question is awkwardly worded. I'm trying to give myself a challenge here and I don't completely understand what I'm trying to do.

Edit: I am not restricted in my solution, and I do not have to use `ContT`.

Comment: Are you restricted to using `ContT` here? This is exactly the sort of situation `Free` or `Operational` was built to handle.

Comment: @Carl I'm not restricted at all, and I'm definitely open to exploring those solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @Carl, I think `FT Cmd m` is more likely than `Free Cmd`.

Comment: You might need an existential wrapper. It's hard to understand if you actually need that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Either your commands all need to be closures that return the same type (such as `IO ()`, in which case you can’t do `getChar`) or you need to have a polymorphic result type that can hold either `IO ()` or `IO Char`, and `ContinueIO` needs to take this as its argument.  Then you need to decide what happens when you pass an `IO Char` to `GetChar` or nothing to `PutChar`.  (This version could be a `Monoid` with `<> = ContinueIO` and `mempty = id`, and then you could `foldMap` over any `Foldable` structure.)

Comment: With a polymorphic result type, how will the continuation know what to return?

Comment: Has to be defined for each case. `GetChar` would return a `Char` wrapped in an `IO Result` or whatever you call it, and `PutChar` would return `()`. They’d call different constructors.

Comment: You could also do a more complicated AST, where a `GetChar` node has a daughter node that the type system will only let you fill with something that takes an `IO Char` as input, and if you want to ignore the result, you put in an ignore-a-`Char` command as the terminal node.